# A nice formula for area of the triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry

The following problem can be found in S.L. Loney's *The Elements of Coordinate Geometry* (Examples X, Problem 19):

> Prove that the if the area of the triangle formed by the three straight lines $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0, a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0, a_3x+b_3y+c_3=0$ is $A$, then
>
> $\displaystyle (a_2b_1-b_2a_1)(a_3b_1-b_3a_1)(a_2b_3-b_2a_3)A = \frac12 \begin{vmatrix}
> a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\ 
> a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ 
> a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\ 
> \end{vmatrix}^2$.

Now one can solve this problem by finding the points of intersections and using the the determinant formula for the area of the triangle.

I want to know if there is a slick proof (especially using vectors). The determinant and the expressions $a_2b_1-b_1a_2$ are reminiscent of cross products.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901819/direct-formula-for-area-of-a-triangle-formed-by-three-lines-given-their-equatio) question was one of my first on this site. I found Blue's proof really interesting btw.

Comment: @Isomorphism yes, there is a proof by vectors, look at my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999990/59379) in the duplicated question which uses homogeneous coordinates.