# Find area of triangle with equation of each line and vertex?

Tags: geometry

Equation of three lines:
$$X=0$$
$$Y=-2x+12$$
$$Y=0.5x+4.5$$
Therefore the vertices of the triangle are: 
$(3,6),
(0,12),
(0,4.5)$
But i dont know what to do next to work out the area because i dont have a length?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Also see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901819/direct-formula-for-area-of-a-triangle-formed-by-three-lines-given-their-equatio) if you want to skip the vertices and directly get the area.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say $A = (3,6), B = (0,12), C = (0,4.5)$.

Now find the vectors $BA = A-B=(3-0,6-12)^T=(3,-6)^T$ and $BC = C-B=(0-0,4.5-12)^T=(0-7.5)^T$.

Now use the Formula for the Area:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}|\det{[BA,BC]}|$$

Can you make it from here?

You can also use the formula $A=\frac{1}{2}|BA||BC|\sin(\alpha)$. You can get the $\alpha$ from the dot product $<BA,BC>=|BA||BC|\cos(\alpha)$.

You can also calculatr the magnitude of the cross product (add zero als third component for both vectors) and then multiply by 1/2 to get the area.

Comment: Yh thanks mate should