# Possible projective duality between two determinantal formulas for triangle area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, determinant, triangles, projective-geometry

The [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) for the area of a polygon in terms of consecutive vertices is well-known. In the particular case of a triangle, this may be written using a 3-by-3 determinant as

$$\text{area of triangle}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$
where $(x_k,y_k)_{k=1,2,3}$ are the three vertices. Several proofs have appeared on this site already.

What may be surprising is that there's another determinantal formula for the area in terms of the three *lines*. Specifically, a triangle with lines $a_k x+b_k y+c_k=0$ for $k=1,2,3$ satisfies

$$\text{area of triangle}=\frac{1}{2C_1C_2C_3}\begin{vmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{vmatrix}^2$$ where $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are the cofactors of the third column. (An older [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901819/137524) has multiple proofs.)

The parallels between these formulas intrigue me: Both express the area of a triangle in terms of a determinant, but one in terms of *points* and the other in terms of *lines*. This is reminiscent of the duality of lines and points in projective geometry. Hence my question: Can these the two formulas indeed be understood through projective duality?

Comment: Note: I am _not_ interested in additional proofs of such, since they're already available on this site. I'm also not interested in seeing an algebraic proof that the two are equivalent _unless_ it gives insight into how they formulas are related.

Comment: In homogeneous coordinates for $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$, the line through a pair of points can be represented by their cross product, which can be written as a determinant. You might find a connection between the formulas that way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the connection between these two formulas is just a consequence of Cramer's rule.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Let us assume that $a_jx_i+b_jy_i+c_j=0$, whenever $i\neq j$, and $d_i=a_ix_i+b_iy_i+c_i$. Since this is a triangle then $d_i\neq 0$, for every $i$.

Hence, $AB=\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & d_3\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x_1}{d_1} & \frac{x_2}{d_2} & \frac{x_3}{d_3} \\ \frac{y_1}{d_1} & \frac{y_2}{d_2} & \frac{y_3}{d_3} \\ \frac{1}{d_1} & \frac{1}{d_2} & \frac{1}{d_3}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

By Cramer's rule, $\frac{1}{\det(A)}\begin{vmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & 1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & 0 \\ a_3 & b_3 & 0\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{d_1}$, $\frac{1}{\det(A)}\begin{vmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & 0 \\ a_2 & b_2 & 1 \\ a_3 & b_3 & 0\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{d_2}$, $\frac{1}{\det(A)}\begin{vmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & 0 \\ a_2 & b_2 & 0 \\ a_3 & b_3 & 1\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{d_3}$.

So $\det(AB)=d_1d_2d_3=\dfrac{\det(A)^3}{C_1C_2C_3}$. Thus, $\det(B)=\dfrac{\det(A)^2}{C_1C_2C_3}$.

Comment: The (correct) way you use Cramer's formulas can be a little misleading. You should say that you transform your matrix equality $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x_1}{d_1} & \frac{x_2}{d_2} & \frac{x_3}{d_3} \\ \frac{y_1}{d_1} & \frac{y_2}{d_2} & \frac{y_3}{d_3} \\ \frac{1}{d_1} & \frac{1}{d_2} & \frac{1}{d_3}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ into 3 linear systems (ctd...)

Comment: (...ctd) the first one being $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x_1}{d_1} \\ \frac{y_1}{d_1} \\ \frac{1}{d_1} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ etc. and that you apply Cramer's rule to these  3 different systems (call them (1) (2) (3)) for getting the first element in (1), the second element in (2), the third element in (3).

Comment: besides, very interesting presentation.