# Find $m>1/2$ that minimizes the area of the triangle formed by lines $y=10-2x$, $y=mx$, $y=-x/m$

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, area

I am tackling this problem below:

> A triangle is formed by the three lines 
>   $$\begin{align}
> y &=10-2x \\ 
> y &= mx \\
> y   &=-\frac{x}{m}
> \end{align}$$ where $m>\frac{1}{2}$. Find the value of $m$ for which the area of the triangle is a minimum.

My thoughts are these:

I tried to draw the three graphs nothe rectangular coordinate, and since $m> \frac{1}{2}$, $-\frac{1}{m}>2$, but after that how can I decide the area of triangle formed?

Comment: Are you able to find the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle?  What formulas do you know for area of a triangle and which formula uses information that is most conveniently found using what you have available in this problem?  (*My initial instinct is to use [heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) but have not bothered to work it out yet and other people may have other opinions*)

Comment: It's a bit of overkill, but see ["Direct formula for area of a triangle formed by three lines, given their equations in the cartesian plane"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901819/409), which calculates the triangle's area using determinants based on the line equations. [My solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/906793/409) walks through a geometric derivation; the reader is invited to adapt it to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell_1$ be the line with equation $y = 10-2x$, let $\ell_2$ be the line with equation $y = mx$, and let $\ell_3$ be the line with equation $y = \frac{-x}{m}$.  Then the lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ intersect at 
$$P = \left( \frac{10}{m+2}, \frac{10m}{m+2} \right),$$
and the lines the lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_3$ intersect at
$$
Q = \left( \frac{-10m}{1-2m}, \frac{10}{1-2m} \right).
$$
If $O = (0,0)$, then the line segments $\overline{OP}$ and $\overline{OQ}$ are orthogonal, which means that the area of the triangle is given by
$$
A = \frac{1}{2} \left|OP\right| \left| OQ\right| 
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{10 \sqrt{1+m^2}}{m+2} \right) \left( \frac{10 \sqrt{1+m^2}}{1-2m} \right) = \frac{50(1+m^2)}{(m+2)(1-2m)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Although an answer is given, I want to add my answer too, which is less tedious.

It is clear that the lines $y=mx$ and $y=\frac{-x}{m}$ are perpendicular and their point of intersection is the origin.

The other side is $2x+y-10=0$

Since we need to calculate the area of the triangle, we can always use $\frac{h×b}{2}$ instead of coordinates. Perpendicular distance on the line from origin is $\frac{10}{\sqrt{5}}=2\sqrt{5}$.

Now we use that our triangle is right triangle. It is trivial from here. The minimum area is $(2\sqrt{5})^2=20$.