# How to calculating area of a triangle formed by three lines using direct formula?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, determinant, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I tried using below stated amazing formula:

Then the area of the triangle that these lines will enclose is given by the magnitude of :
$$\frac{det\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{bmatrix}^2}{2C_1C_2C_3}$$
[*Where $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are the co-factors of $c_1,c_2,c_3$ respectively in the above matrix.*] [ref.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901819/direct-formula-for-area-of-a-triangle-formed-by-three-lines-given-their-equatio?newreg=60ebc4c670f64e2fb38ec08edad5c52b)

But couldn't get the desired answer. System of linear questions are as follows.

$$2x+3y+-6=0$$
$$3x+2y+6=0$$
$$3x+-3y+6=0$$

I end up getting decimal answers!

Comment: I calculate the area is $10$ using other method, are you sure $17.25$ is correct?

Comment: @AbelWong which method? Can you share link of your wrong work or method you use?

Comment: Also, you can find discuss of this formula at [Area formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901819/direct-formula-for-area-of-a-triangle-formed-by-three-lines-given-their-equatio)

Comment: @AbelWong that's okay but is that the correct answer? (May be my calculation might be wrong using Area formula you are using but answer is correct? And do you care to share your work as answer?

Comment: @AbelWong can you please share your work as answer? I will accept it.

Comment: You should take into account that correct formula includes $det(A)^2$ not $det(A^2)$. Then $S=\frac{150^2}{2\cdot 15 \cdot 15 \cdot 5}=10$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu thanks thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the first thing you need to do is find the length of each of the triangle's sides. You can do this by finding the intersection points of the lines, and the corresponding distances between them.

Let the lines be:
$l_1(x)=a_1x+b_1$
$l_2(x)=a_2x+b_2$
$l_3(x)=a_3x+b_3$

Your three points of intersection will then be:

$(\frac{b_2-b_1}{a_1-a_2}, (\frac{b_2-b_1}{a_1-a_2})x+b_1$)
$(\frac{b_3-b_2}{a_2-a_3}, (\frac{b_3-b_2}{a_2-a_3})x+b_2)$
$(\frac{b_1-b_3}{a_3-a_1}, (\frac{b_1-b_3}{a_3-a_1})x+b_3)$

Calculate the distance between each of these points using the formula $d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$.

Once you've obtained that, let the three side lengths be $a,b,c$. Using Heron's formula, $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}:A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve those equations.

We can find the intersect points are $(0,2), (-2,0), (-6,6)$

Since it is so symmetry, you have plenty of method to find the area.

A simple method:

$Area = \frac{bh}{2} = \frac{2\sqrt{2} \times 5\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{10 \times 2}{2} =10$

Or subtraction area of two triangle with base on x-axis may be even easier.

$Area = \frac{5 \times 6}{2} -\frac{5 \times 2}{2} = 10$

Or use determinant formula. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753247/area-of-three-points-in-2d-is-equal-to-a-determinant)

Comment: You are using different method than direct formula.